# Would like code improvement on C# TCP listener to SQL Server database app

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp

I have built a C# console app that accepts TCP connections from GPS reporting devices I have. I built this app to collect that data and dump it into a SQL Server table.

Currently, I have the application working, but it has a bug I can't seem to figure out. As the GPS devices make connections, one out of random 1-10 successful connections give me an index out of range exception.

When I dump the raw data it does not look like something the device is sending me. Would any of you happen to know what is causing this? Also, once I get this application working correctly, it could be receiving up to 3-5k connections a minute, do you think this code could handle this?

This is the error I receive every so often, with the dump of misc data:

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on9M0.png)

This is my code:

```
namespace GPS2DB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("10.71.150.253");

                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Tracker Connections...");

                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 10000);

                listener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");

                    var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {

                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        int size = client.Receive(data);
                        string gpsData = "";

                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(data[i]));
                            gpsData = gpsData + Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
                        }

                        string txt = gpsData;
                        string txt2 = (txt.Trim(new Char[] { '$', '#' }));

                        String[] values = txt2.Split(',');
                        //Console.WriteLine(txt2);
                        /*
                        Console.WriteLine("Unit ID: " + values[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Event Code: " + values[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine("UTC Date: " + values[2]);
                        Console.WriteLine("UTC Time: " + values[3]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + values[4]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Long: " + values[5]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Speed: " + values[7]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Heading: " + values[11]);
                        Console.WriteLine("V+: " + values[16]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Cell Strength: " + values[17]);
                        Console.WriteLine("GPS Status: " + values[18]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Fuel Level: " + values[20]);
                        */

                        //dump 2 database
                        string connectionString = "Data Source=DVT501;Initial Catalog=VehicleTracking;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=TABLE;Password=PASS";

                        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Data_Dump (uid, eventCode, utcDate, utcTime, lat, long, speed, heading, voltage, cellStrength, gpsStatus, fuelLevel) VALUES (@uid, @eventCode, @utcDate, @utcTime, @lat, @long, @speed, @heading, @voltage, @cellStrength, @gpsStatus, @fuelLevel)");
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.Connection = connection;

                            try
                            { 

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", values[0]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventCode", values[1]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utcDate", values[2]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utcTime", values[3]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lat", values[4]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@long", values[5]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@speed", values[7]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@heading", values[11]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voltage", values[16]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellStrength", values[17]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gpsStatus", values[18]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuelLevel", values[20]);

                            connection.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("IndexOutOfRangeException caught" + e);
                            Console.WriteLine(txt);
                        }
                    }

                    //end dump
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    client.Close();
                });

                childSocketThread.Start();
             }

             listener.Stop();
          }               
          catch (Exception e)
          {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
                Console.ReadLine();
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# does not handle connections pooling the way like lets say `Delphi` so if you are expecting that many connections / minute.. you are not going to be happy with the fact that you will run into issues.. also try creating a List<T> to stored the gps data in and see if you still get the same error..

Comment: Slight deviation from the topic at hand. AddWithValue can misinterpret datatypes when doing pass through sql like this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

The error is with the incoming data, it's either a gps device that's configured to send data differently or some random tcp event. Check the port number you're using in a google search and make sure it's not reserved for something else.

This code will definitely not handle that many connections, you iterate through a byte array and convert one character at a time (use System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byte[]) instead), you open and close a connection to the sql server within the receive block and so on. In order to handle that kind of activity you need to just read the data and put it in a bus or temp storage to be bulk processed.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that you will read one message at a time. TCP provides a boundaryless stream of bytes. You can very well read a partial message or multiple messages.

How to deal with that depends on the format of the stream. If it is line based `StreamReader.ReadLine()` is a great solution.